# String Length Expensive

Tags: c#, performance

I have two string values and I want to sum lengths of these two strings. How can calculate best way?

first:

```
string firstStr = "this a first message";
string secondStr = "this a second message";
int total = firstStr.Length + secondStr.Length;
```

second:

```
string firstStr = "this a first message";
string secondStr = "this a second message";
int total = (firstStr + secondStr).Length;
```

or other?

Comment: Is performance your concern? It is a micro optimization. But in general it is better to avoid string concatenation.

Comment: @KonradKokosa is right. the second is MUCH slower.

Comment: strings are immutable, so definitely the first

Comment: From my experience, there is absolutely nothing you would need the length of strings for that would affect performance (of the program)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first way is more efficient, because it simply adds two numbers.

The second way is wasteful, because it creates a new object, copies the content of two strings into it, counts the length, and then discards the temporary object - hardly an efficient use of the CPU!

Another way to compare the two is to compare their asymptotic times - O(1) for the first solution, and O(m+n) for the second solution. The first computation completes in constant time, because string lengths are readily available. The second computation requires copying the content of each string, which is linear.

Answer (score 6):

First is probably faster because your string object already know his length. The second you add a concatenation operation.

Answer (score 2):

**Second version is creating a new string instance** and then getting its length. It should be expensive. But whatever the difference would be it would be negligible for the above line of codes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option doesn't create a new string, so in my book it's better.

`int total = firstStr.Length + secondStr.Length;`

Answer (score 0):

The first is more efficient, because it doesn't involve the creation of a third string through concatenation.
In the first case you just have to add up the length of two objects you already have in memory, without wasting memory / time.

Answer (score -1):

i did a couple of test runs, doing 1M runs of each approach

first approach: 38,189 ms

second approach: 50,4055 ms

here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch watch;

        watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        First();
        watch.Stop();
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("first: {0} ms",watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));

        watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Second();
        watch.Stop();
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("second: {0} ms", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
    }

    static void First()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string firstStr = "this a first message";
            string secondStr = "this a second message";
            int total = firstStr.Length + secondStr.Length;
        }

    }

    static void Second()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string firstStr = "this a first message";
            string secondStr = "this a second message";
            int total = (firstStr + secondStr).Length;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Benchmarking micro-optimizations is *really* hard.  It's virtually never done in such a way as to provide meaningful insight as to what's going on.  Without seeing any testing code, this is virtually meaningless.

Comment: Yes i know benchmarking micro-optimizations is hard. But in this case the test is pretty isolated, and did it just because of self interest. The test code is the code in the original question.

Comment: ms means milliseconds and not seconds. I added sample code so you can see what the test looks like.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that, but 1000 of those milliseconds equals a second, so instead of saying 50,000 milliseconds, I just said 50 seconds.

Comment: ok, sorry for the number formatting confusion :) perhaps a different localization setting in my VS output window